# More space needed between badges and numbers

Tags: bug, design, badges

In both the question list and on the question itself, there is not enough room between certain numbers and the badge icon they go with (images zoomed in for effect):

[image]

> [image]

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/346503/153006) is my question for an example of this happening. [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions) is the questions list where you can also see this happen. Meta does not have this problem.

I think the issue is with the badge icons because I even notice a spacing difference between meta and main with my badges in the top bar, though the spacing is always acceptable there.

I am using Chrome on Mac. I wonder if anyone else sees this on another setup.

Comment: Thanks for the report, the SE team is aware of this and is planning to fix it - see the answer on the duplicate question :)